# Histogram of three uneven datasets

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

I have three data sets consisting of times (hours) when something happened. The data sets have 2005, 826, 276 events respectively, so they're quite disproportionate.

What I wanted to do was show how the events are distributed over 24 hours, so I created a histogram. But, as the first data set is much larger than the others, the resulting graph just looks like the first data set's distribution.

How can I transform my data to ensure that each data set gets the same amount of impact on the resulting distribution?

I'm using the Python NumPy library to plot my data, so a method using this library would be preferred. I was using the [numpy.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) function.

Comment: Perhaps for each hour, instead of plotting the number of events you could plot the percentage of events (out of the total number in the data set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed vadim123's advice and this the following:
For each data set I counted the number of events for each hour divided by the number of total events in that data set. After that I combined the three resulting distributions and divided each percentage by the number of data sets.

Thanks for the help!